# Class variables in REACT

Tags: reactjs

Does class variables in a class need to be a part of the stateObject? I tried below with no luck. Here there is samples with simple variables so I am kind of surprice below does not work (alert says undefined)?

https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_es6.asp

https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-glade-lfv4f?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Test extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.variable = "works";
  }

  clicked() {
    alert(this.variable);
  }

  render() {
    return <div onClick={this.clicked}>CLICK ME</div>;
  }
}

export default Test;
```

Comment: Try to use arrow function `clicked = () => { ... }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `bind()` call to make it work.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.variable = "works";
  this.clicked = this.clicked.bind(this);
}
```

for more information on this checkout [Handling events in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

Why you have to bind here? so this is because you are using ES6 syntax for your components, and in ES6 class methods are not [bound](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to classes by default, and to be able to use `this` keyword inside your methods and make it refer to the class instance you have bind your method to the class like in this answer.

Comment: Kind of strange your binding the event. The event actually works. Is it because you need to bind events before you can use local variables within them?

Comment: I added more explanation in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Test extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.variable = "works";
  }

  clicked = () => {
    alert(this.variable);
  }

  render() {
    return <div onClick={this.clicked}>CLICK ME</div>;
  }
}

export default Test;
```

You can choose not to `bind` but you need to be adding `fat-arrow` function syntax in order to make it work.

Comment: it is not working https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-shadow-mdtv2

Comment: ah ok now works. So it is not about fat-arrow func or bind, just using arrow function is ok

Comment: Thanks for your input, appreciated.